# Validar formulários e gerar páginas dinâmicas

Tags: javascript

Utilizo javascript para validar formulários com php+html, diante das constantes alterações (evoluções da linguagem e tecnologia) atualmente o javascript ainda continua sendo recomendado a sua utilização ou já existe possibilidade de substituir o javascript por uma outra linguagem Client-Side.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4872/como-usar-outra-linguagem-que-n%C3%A3o-javascript-no-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma resposta definitiva para essa questão, já que esta mais relacionada com a opinião de cada um.

Aí vai a minha.

Apesar de outras linguagens como Typescript (Microsoft), Dart (Google) e Coffee Script, a maior parte dos browsers suporta apenas Javascript.

A iniciativa da Microsoft com a linguagem Typescript é até que interessante, já que o "compilador" (é mais um tradutor que um compilador) gera código Javascript, e portanto pode ser executada em qualquer browser. A linguagem Typescript, assim, é um super set de JS.

Nunca mexi com nenhuma delas, e portanto não sei dizer suas vantagens específicas, com exceção do fato da compatibilidade da Typescript.

Hoje, o que eu tenho feito, é utilizar frameworks para o desenvolvimento do código do cliente, já que não há como fugir do JS.

O que melhor me adaptei (embora o esteja usando a pouco tempo), é o AngularJS. Ele é simples, a documentação é estensa (porém não completa), é possível integrá-lo com várias outras bibliotecas (como Bootstrap e jQuery) e criar coisas muito legais, que favorecem demais a reusabilidade de código.

Gostei muito também do Google Closure, mas ele é mais complicado e exige muito mais do desenvolvedor que o AngularJS.

Enfim, na minha experiência, não fuja de Javascript (pelo menos não por enquanto...), e faça uso de Frameworks sempre que possível.

Comment: +1, me atualizei com a sua resposta. jQuery é o que uso, mas vou dar uma olhada nos citados.

Comment: eu vi vários caras que trabalham com empresas grandes nos EUA falando que o Javascript como linguagem client-side e suas variações como Jquery são e serão por muito tempo ainda as tecnologias mais utilizadas para desenvolvimento de sistemas para web por ser uma linguagem que funciona em qualquer lugar que você colocar, além de ser mega robusta e também falando que quem tem segurança no que está fazendo e no seu nível profissional não se importa com a exposição do seu código fonte. Eu pessoalmente respeito estes caras.

Comment: Extensa é com 'x'.