# Escrever codigo VB em arquivo .JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

É possível escrever um código em vb dentro de um arquivo que esteja como .js?

Por exemplo:
`arquivo teste.js`

```
var testeEvento = function () {
    <%=MsgBox("teste")%>;
    };
```

Tentei deste jeito nao funcionou ele me retorna isso:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

E ao executar:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testeEvento is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar outra linguagem que não JavaScript no browser?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4872/como-usar-outra-linguagem-que-n%c3%a3o-javascript-no-browser)

Comment: É tipo querer usar `c#` em um `.java` , não rola, a não ser que você processe esse `js` como um arquivo `T4` no lado do servidor e envie para a tela compilado.

Comment: tendi nada mano

Comment: Não, não é possível.